# rename the .N column in data table

Tags: r, list, data.table

Hi I have a question on renaming the .N in data.table when aggregating data.

For example:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(mtcars) 

> # try to rename the ".N" with "Count"

# get mode number
> mode <- function(x){
+   ux <- na.omit(unique(x))
+   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x,ux)))]
+ }

> #1  wrong  
> DT[ , c(lapply(.SD, sum), Count=.N), by = (cyl)]
   cyl   mpg   disp   hp  drat     wt   qsec vs am gear carb  N
1:   6 138.2 1283.2  856 25.10 21.820 125.84  4  3   27   24  7
2:   4 293.3 1156.5  909 44.78 25.143 210.51 10  8   45   17 11
3:   8 211.4 4943.4 2929 45.21 55.989 234.81  0  2   46   49 14

> #2 correct
> DT[ , c(lapply(.SD, sum), .(Count=.N)), by = (cyl)]
   cyl   mpg   disp   hp  drat     wt   qsec vs am gear carb Count
1:   6 138.2 1283.2  856 25.10 21.820 125.84  4  3   27   24     7
2:   4 293.3 1156.5  909 44.78 25.143 210.51 10  8   45   17    11
3:   8 211.4 4943.4 2929 45.21 55.989 234.81  0  2   46   49    14

> #3 wrong
> DT[ , c(lapply(.SD, sum), Count=.N, mpg2=max(mpg)), by = (cyl)]
   cyl   mpg   disp   hp  drat     wt   qsec vs am gear carb  N mpg2
1:   6 138.2 1283.2  856 25.10 21.820 125.84  4  3   27   24  7 21.4
2:   4 293.3 1156.5  909 44.78 25.143 210.51 10  8   45   17 11 33.9
3:   8 211.4 4943.4 2929 45.21 55.989 234.81  0  2   46   49 14 19.2

> #4 correct
> DT[ , c(lapply(.SD, sum), Count=.N, mpg2=mode(mpg)), by = (cyl)]
   cyl   mpg   disp   hp  drat     wt   qsec vs am gear carb Count mpg2
1:   6 138.2 1283.2  856 25.10 21.820 125.84  4  3   27   24     7 21.0
2:   4 293.3 1156.5  909 44.78 25.143 210.51 10  8   45   17    11 22.8
3:   8 211.4 4943.4 2929 45.21 55.989 234.81  0  2   46   49    14 15.2
```

1. why does the #1 can not rename the .N correctly?
2. why does the #4 can rename the .N correctly? It should be same as #1 and #3;

Answer (score 3):

According to `?datatable.optimize`

> The expression dt[, lapply(.SD, fun), by=.] gets optimised to dt[, list(fun(a), fun(b), ...), by=.] where a,b, ... are columns in .SD. This improves performance tremendously.

We can make the optimizations on and off

```
options(datatable.optimize = 1L) # optimisation 'on'  default case
 DT[ , c(lapply(.SD, sum), Count=.N, mpg2=max(mpg)), by = (cyl)]
options(datatable.optimize = 0L) # optimisation 'off'
DT[ , c(lapply(.SD, sum), Count=.N, mpg2=max(mpg)), by = (cyl)]
 cyl   mpg   disp    hp  drat     wt   qsec    vs    am  gear  carb Count  mpg2
   <num> <num>  <num> <num> <num>  <num>  <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <int> <num>
1:     6 138.2 1283.2   856 25.10 21.820 125.84     4     3    27    24     7  21.4
2:     4 293.3 1156.5   909 44.78 25.143 210.51    10     8    45    17    11  33.9
3:     8 211.4 4943.4  2929 45.21 55.989 234.81     0     2    46    49    14  19.2
```

---

When we create a function, it is not having an optimized function i.e. only some functions have gforce optimizations i.e. `gsum`, `gmin`, `gmax` etc.  Try running with `verbose = TRUE` which will print all the intermediate steps

```
DT[ , c(lapply(.SD, sum), Count=.N, mpg2=get("max")(mpg)),
    by = (cyl), verbose = TRUE]
```

vs.

```
DT[ , c(lapply(.SD, sum), Count=.N, mpg2= max(mpg)), by = (cyl), 
        verbose = TRUE]
```

Also, if we create a function ie. on the fly with `max` it wouldn't trigger the optimization

```
options(datatable.optimize = 1L) #
new1 <- function(x) max(x)
DT[ , c(lapply(.SD, sum), Count=.N, mpg2=new1(mpg)), by = (cyl)]
     cyl   mpg   disp    hp  drat     wt   qsec    vs    am  gear  carb Count  mpg2
   <num> <num>  <num> <num> <num>  <num>  <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <int> <num>
1:     6 138.2 1283.2   856 25.10 21.820 125.84     4     3    27    24     7  21.4
2:     4 293.3 1156.5   909 44.78 25.143 210.51    10     8    45    17    11  33.9
3:     8 211.4 4943.4  2929 45.21 55.989 234.81     0     2    46    49    14  19.2
```